# How to check svn writable access rights programmatically?

Tags: php, svn, pear

I'm using subversion using [`PEAR/VersionControl_SVN`](http://pear.php.net/package/VersionControl_SVN/) library. Advantage of this library is that it is a wrapper for subversion command line client. Therefore, I do not need to install any bindings/modules/extensions (such as [svn extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php)) in order to work with subversion directly using embedded functions (such as [`svn_ls`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.svn-ls.php) or [`svn_commit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.svn-commit.php)). All my application needs for functioning is subversion command line client installed. Bad thing is that if something cannot be done using subversion command line client, then it is impossible to do using this library.

For example, I could not find any other the way to check whether user have writable access to the repository except trying to create and delete `/test` directory and then analyze output:

```
require_once 'VersionControl/SVN.php';

class SvnException extends Exception {};

function checkCredentials($url, $user, $password) {
    $switches = array(
        'username' => $user, 
        'password' => $password, 
        'message' => 'check whether user '.$user.' has repository writable access'
    );
    $svnerror = &PEAR_ErrorStack::singleton('VersionControl_SVN');
    $svnoptions = array('fetchmode' => VERSIONCONTROL_SVN_FETCHMODE_ARRAY);
    $action = VersionControl_SVN::factory('mkdir', $svnoptions);
    $url = rtrim($url, '/\ ');
    $action->run(array($url.'/test'), $switches);
    $action = VersionControl_SVN::factory('delete', $svnoptions);
    $action->run(array($url.'/test'), $switches);
    if($errors = $svnerror->getErrors()) {
        $all_errors = '';
        foreach ($errors as $err) {
            $all_errors .= $err['message']."\n";
        }
        throw new SvnException($all_errors);
    }
    return true;
}

$url = 'svn://localhost:3129';
$user = 'username';
$password = 'password';
try {
    if(checkCredentials($url, $user, $password)) {
        print "User $user has writable access to subversion repository $url\n";
    }
} catch (SvnException $e) {
    print "User $user does not have writable access to subversion repository $url\n";
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```

Output is following:

```
> php checksvnaccess.php

User username does not have writable access to subversion repository svn://localhost:3129

svn: E160013: URL 'svn://localhost:3129/test' does not exist (cmd: "C:\Program F
iles\Subversion Client\svn.EXE" delete --username username --password password -
-message "check whether user username has repository writable access" "svn://loc
alhost:3129/test")

svn: E170001: SASL authentication error: SASL(-1): generic failure: Unable to fi
nd a callback: 2 (cmd: "C:\Program Files\Subversion Client\svn.EXE" mkdir --user
name username --password password --message "check whether user username has rep
ository writable access" "svn://localhost:3129/test")

Username: Password for '': (cmd: "C:\Program Files\Subversion Client\svn.EXE" mk
dir --username username --password password --message "check whether user userna
me has repository writable access" "svn://localhost:3129/test")

Authentication realm: <svn://localhost:3129> 76572ec9-2173-de46-8e99-8db01e97341
a (cmd: "C:\Program Files\Subversion Client\svn.EXE" mkdir --username username -
-password password --message "check whether user username has repository writabl
e access" "svn://localhost:3129/test")
```

Executing this code sample is the same as running following commands:

```
svn mkdir --username username --password password --message "check whether user username has repository writable access" "svn://localhost:3129/test"
svn delete --username username --password password --message "check whether user username has repository writable access" "svn://localhost:3129/test"
```

Is there any way to check repository access rights using this library without trying to create some object in a repository? It would be great if there was a way to check access using command line. For example, `svn checkaccess --username username --password password svn://localhost:3129/test`. Is there any workaround?

Comment: SVN repository access may be paths-based (one path can be writable for some users but not writable for others; another path can have own rule).

Comment: yes, right. and is there a way to check writable access rights for path?

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593587/check-subversion-writable-access-for-user