# Check subversion writable access for user

Tags: svn, version-control, permissions, repository

Is there any way to check whether user have writable access to some repository path? What I do now is trying to create directory and then delete it to check whether user has writable access:

```
svn mkdir --username username --password password --message "check whether user username has repository writable access" "svn://localhost:3129/test"
svn delete --username username --password password --message "check whether user username has repository writable access" "svn://localhost:3129/test"
```

The problem is that those operations are performed too often as a part of application source code. And, as a result, repository get too many needless commits in case user has writable access.

Is there any command similar to `svn checkaccess --username username --password password svn://localhost:3129/test` or any other workarounds so that I would not need to create temporary directory all the time?

Answer (score 1):

I can propose a hacky way, but I'm not sure it will work for all protocols (I tested with DAV --- it worked, with file:/// all paths are writable).

Subversion has several APIs. Some languages (at least C (libsvn_ra), Java ([SVNKit](http://svnkit.com)), Perl ([AlienSVN](http://search.cpan.org/~mlanier/Alien-SVN-1.6.12.0/))) provide remote API that allows to create a commit with editor calls (I don't know if PHP does). If you perform the following calls on the URL you want to check writability:

```
openRoot -1
changeDirProperty customPropertyName custromPropertyValue
closeDir
abortEdit
```

This sequence performs no changes because of abortEdit() call, if the directory is writable. But for DAV this fails with error code RA_NOT_AUTHORIZED (E170001) if not writable.

There's an [article](http://vcs.atspace.co.uk/2012/07/20/subversion-remote-api-committing-without-working-copy/) that shows how to use commit with SVN remote API in Java. I think PHP code would look similar.

Hope it helps (if not you then at least Java/C/Perl developers).

Comment: Actually, I thought about rewriting SVN module on java using svnkit. But there is still hope I will find php-based solution so that I wouldn't need to rewrite my app.